# Will Converting my H2 memory database to a SQL database mess up any actual logic on my project? Spring Boot

Tags: sql, spring, database, spring-boot, h2

I am currently using the H2 memory database for my website. Everything is working so far but to progress my teacher said to transition from the h2 database to a SQL since it resets everytime you restart the program. I was wondering if I transitioned, would it mess up any of my logic / code. I know I would have to make a database connector class, but I was just curious if I would have to edit the majority of the code so the information can be placed into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what "kind" of "sql code" you have. If you are using Hibernate (e.g. through `spring-data-jpa`) and you only used annotations and never used `@Query("some custom SQL code")`, then you most likely are safe, as Hibernate knows how to translate java annotations to the respective database of your choice (h2, postgres, what have you).

However, if you have used custom queries, then those custom queries might start breaking, depending on the vendor you choose. E.g. if you have `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM users` that would probably work for Microsoft SQL Server, but could fail for Postgres.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I have not used an @query annotations for the insertion into the database. Its a simple Spring Boot website where I have a repo that handles the CRUD, a controller, and jsps.

Comment: Then you will be fine. You need to worry only when you start writing SQL code that is specific to a given vendor (e.g. SQL syntax that is not supported by others). There is a "standard" called ANSI-SQL that defines a number of rules everyone SHOULD comply to (not that they do), and apart from this "standard" everything differs from vendor to vendor (there is no police to look after this :)). E.g. - take a look at the `IF` syntax in different vendors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any form of ORM frameworks like Hibernate, MyBatis, etc and if you are not dependent on any native queries, procedures, functions, etc of the H2 DB. You will be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Shazin! I am using Hibernate and I do not have any @Queries annotations in my code. Phew, seems like an easy transition then.